# My Company is reluctant to move .NET 2.0 Application to the latest. Are there any Security flaws?

Tags: c#

I joined a place where they have an application that is written using VS2005 and .NEt 2.0 Desktop application. Reason why they don't want to move is they are not feeling comfortable and they feel it will break a lot. I feel the opposite. There may be lot Security fixes .NET latest version it was not applied to old version. Is there a Security issue here?
I know there are breaking changes but it will take one or two months to sort it out.

Did any one faced same problem. What are the risk here not to upgrade to the latest version.
I understand .NET 4.5 has whole lot of new functionality it will improve programming experience. Since it is a maintenance application is there a benefit of upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Does it builds successfully when you change the Target platform ?

Comment: It makes no sense to upgrade to newer version of framework if you're not going to use new features and simple recompile old code. I'd suggest leave it be, and start any new development in the new framework.

Comment: As long as Microsoft releases security updates for it, there are no reasons to think that .NET 2.0 is less secure than the newer versions.

Comment: Are you currently experiencing a lot of issue with this legacy system? If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: I could write a novel here.  This is probably very opinionated so I won't post it as answer.
  1. If they feel it will break a lot, then they don't have adequate testing.  Write some automated tests.
  2. I often find that when someone voices fears like this, it often amounts to "that sounds like that will take extra time, so no."
  3. The biggest benefit is that new developers won't go "it's using what?  I'm not maintaining THAT."  Granted, .NET 2.0 isn't ancient yet but at some point it will get frustrating to work with because Visual Studio won't be able to target it any more.

Answer (score 4):

NET 2.0 should be secure. The mainstream support for .NET 2.0 has ended on 4/12/2011 as noted [here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net%20framework). Right now MS offers only extended support till 4/12/2016, which includes security updates as you can see in the table at: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/default.aspx?LN=en-us&x=12&y=15.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you can do is change the target platform and test it. I'd be *very* surprised if it didn't compile right away.

The .NET framework maintains a lot of legacy code to prevent upgrades such as this from breaking, so compilation and run are both unlikely to break, albeit you may get lots of warnings due to Obsolete implementations.

As for the security consideration, consider that one major aspect of the .NET Framework is the reverse compatibility, which means that your application is already running against the newer runtime anyway, depending on the client environment.

As for improvements to the coding environment, note that the newer coding practices require changes to the code, and thus won't simply automatically be taken advantage of, but may offer a way to go back and streamline (both in terms of performance and code readability) older sections of the code. In short, upgrading offers the chance to integrate these newer functionalities, it doesn't include them automatically.

Finally, as mentioned, support for .NET 2.0 has ended, meaning any security flaws discovered won't be patched, making your 2.0 app potentially less secure than a 4.5 one, which gets regular security updates. This is, again, subject to the client runtime, but will prevent a client from running against the possibly insecure 2.0 Runtime.